Point Chart not displaying correctly in WinForms
Why does the following code draws a point (0;0) at a location with coordinates (1;0)? The X value is ignored, I assume the index (number) of the point is taken instead.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace Test3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Series series = new Series("Series1")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point
            };
            series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 0));
            series.MarkerSize = 10;

            Chart chart1=new Chart();
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
            this.Controls.Add(chart1);

            chart1.Series.Clear();
            chart1.Series.Add(series);
        }

    }
}

Changing any Chart parameters, including IsXValueIndexed, did not help.
